How to evaluate the performance of a prediction model across multiple predictions of the same event?
I was thinking of a hypothetical situation where you have a prediction model that can be used to predict the winner of an upcoming football match between Team A and Team B.
Say for the sake of the example, three days before the match, the model is predicting the Team A will win. However, two days before the match, it is revealed that the best player on Team A was hurt during training and will not play, and now the model is predicting that Team B will win. Finally, on the day of the match, the goaltender for Team B tests positive for COVID and is not permitted to play, and now the model is predicting the Team A will win.
The final result of the match is that Team B pulled off a surprise victory!
Is there a way to properly evaluate the performance of the model in this case? It seems difficult to measure since the same model is asked to predict the outcome of the same event but with varying inputs.

The fact that the predictions come from the same model does not change the evaluation. It is only that ther results, e.g. loss, can be correlated. Is that what you are asking about? If so, could you elaborate why you see a problem with this?

Basically, you have a setting, where you want to make a prediction for a point in time (e.g. the match) and new information can come in any time. This means that your prediction changes over time.
Typically, one would not focus on the changes, but on the remaining time. The assumption here is, that surprising changes (e.g. that a player can not join the match) become less likely the closer we are to the match. Hence, the predicitive power of a model will increase when coming closer to the point for which the prediction will be made.
For this reason, you can choose fixed time frames (e.g. 1h, 1d, 2d, 7d before the match) and evalute how well your model performes at this points. Which time frames a reasonable depends on the application. Factors like to typical prediction horizon (how long ahead do you use the model) and frequency of changes will play a role.
You can then report the preditive power for each time frame: How good is your model 1 month before the match. How good is it 1 week before? ...
By using a many time frames, you could even plot a curve of the predictive power of your model over time.

Thanks so much for this clear and concise answer! I would be happy to take more answers from other people but for now this seems like a great solution
